# SQL query cannot be imported in MS Access 2010

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access, split

I have a dbo table in SQL with a column that I need to split up into multiple columns based on a delimiter (,). The code to fulfill this is at the end of this question. The code works perfectly as a query, however I would like to import the final table (so after the split up) in MS Access 2010. That's were it goes wrong, as I cannot find the table with ODBC or the query file. Also, because of the "Declare" function I cannot put this code in a view function. The code is from (it also shows what I want to do with my code): 
https://raresql.com/2015/08/22/sql-server-how-to-split-one-column-into-multiple-columns/

Can you help me with this?

To split up 1 column into multiple columns the code below is used:

```
DECLARE @delimiter VARCHAR(50)
SET @delimiter=', '

;WITH CTE AS
( 
    SELECT  [Tour number], 
            [TISLOT Time slot begin],
            [TISLOT Delivery day],
            [Gate],
            CAST('<M>' + REPLACE([Gate], @delimiter , '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS [Gate XML]
    FROM dbo.TISLOT
)

SELECT  [Tour number], 
        [TISLOT Time slot begin],
        [TISLOT Delivery day],
        [Gate],
        [Gate XML].value('/M[1]', 'varchar(50)') As [Gate1],
        [Gate XML].value('/M[2]', 'varchar(50)') As [Gate2],
        [Gate XML].value('/M[3]', 'varchar(50)') As [Gate3],
        [Gate XML].value('/M[4]', 'varchar(50)') As [Gate4],
        [Gate XML].value('/M[5]', 'varchar(50)') As [Gate5],
        [Gate XML].value('/M[6]', 'varchar(50)') As [Gate6],
        [Gate XML].value('/M[7]', 'varchar(50)') As [Gate7],
        [Gate XML].value('/M[8]', 'varchar(50)') As [Gate8],
        [Gate XML].value('/M[9]', 'varchar(50)') As [Gate9],
        [Gate XML].value('/M[10]', 'varchar(50)') As [Gate10]
FROM CTE 
GO
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Why don't you exclude the declare and use
Replace([Gate], ', ', ''). You don't have variables and can make a view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put your code into stored procedure. Then call it from Access and put it into table with the help of recordset:

```
Dim db As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim rstCurr As DAO.Recordset
Dim dbsCurr As Database

db.Open "Provider=SQLNCLI11;Server=SERVER\INSTANCE;Database=MyDataBase;Trusted_Connection=yes;"
db.CommandTimeout = 180
db.CursorLocation = adUseClient

Set rs = db.Execute("EXEC dbo.StoredProc")

Set dbsCurr = Access.CurrentDb
Set rstCurr = dbsCurr.OpenRecordset("AccessTable", dbOpenDynaset)

Do Until rs.EOF

    rstCurr.AddNew
    rstCurr.Fields(0).value = rs.Fields(0).value
    rstCurr.Fields(1).value = rs.Fields(1).value
    ...

    rstCurr.Update
    rs.MoveNext
Loop

Set rs = Nothing
db.Close: Set db = Nothing
```

Comment: This works perfectly. However I used the code below for the reading in access:


Create a new query in Access, don't add any tables. Click Query ~ SQL Specific ~ Pass-Through. In the SQL window, type your statement e.g.

EXEC usp_MyProcedure '6/6/2008'

then click View ~ Properties and under the ODBC Connect String click the build button (...) and select a DSN that points to your SQL database.

Thanks guys

Answer (score 2):

Consider two special query objects (both available on Ribbon) in MS Access:

1. Pass-Through query that allows you to retain the SQL Server
   syntax of the connected BackEnd but run from inside MS Access; this will require specifying ODBC/OLEDB settings on creation.
2. Make-Table action query to produce a local Access table from above pass
   through query.

**Pass-Through** Query

*(save as a stored, pass-through query object, slightly adjusted the CTE into a derived table but no reason CTE couldn't work)*

```
SELECT  [Tour number], 
        [TISLOT Time slot begin],
        [TISLOT Delivery day],
        [Gate],
        [Gate XML].value('/M[1]', 'varchar(50)') As [Gate1],
        [Gate XML].value('/M[2]', 'varchar(50)') As [Gate2],
        [Gate XML].value('/M[3]', 'varchar(50)') As [Gate3],
        [Gate XML].value('/M[4]', 'varchar(50)') As [Gate4],
        [Gate XML].value('/M[5]', 'varchar(50)') As [Gate5],
        [Gate XML].value('/M[6]', 'varchar(50)') As [Gate6],
        [Gate XML].value('/M[7]', 'varchar(50)') As [Gate7],
        [Gate XML].value('/M[8]', 'varchar(50)') As [Gate8],
        [Gate XML].value('/M[9]', 'varchar(50)') As [Gate9],
        [Gate XML].value('/M[10]', 'varchar(50)') As [Gate10]
FROM 
   ( 
    SELECT  [Tour number], 
            [TISLOT Time slot begin],
            [TISLOT Delivery day],
            [Gate],
            CAST('<M>' + REPLACE([Gate], ',' , '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS [Gate XML]
    FROM dbo.TISLOT 
   ) AS dT
```

**Make-Table** Query

*(action query can be run one time or saved as a stored query object for regular use)*

```
SELECT * 
INTO [NewMSAccessLocalTable]
FROM [SQLServerPassThruQuery]
```